# ¿Como guardar la fk de un modelo en django?

Tags: python, django, vistas

Tengo un modelo que se llama dispositivo, este crea el folio y el nombre y adicional quiero almacenar el id del usuario que está logueado. Esta es mi clase:

```
class RegistroDispositivo(CreateView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'registroDispositivo.html'
    form_class = RegistroDevice
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    def post(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        usuario = request.user
        if usuario:
            user_id = User.objects.get(email=usuario)
            form = self.form_class(initial={'user_id':user_id})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            form = self.form_class()
        return super(RegistroDispositivo, self).post(form)
```

Mi models.py incluye un abstractBaseUser para otras funcionalidades adicionales al user de Django

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nombreEmpresa = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

class Device(models.Model):
    folio = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    deviceName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Hola Diego, por favor incluye tu models.py en la pregunta para poder evaluar y ayudarte

Comment: Listo @jsanchezs así queda mi modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto. La mas sencilla seria sobreescribir form_valid en tu clase. Quedaría algo asi:

```
class RegistroDispositivo(CreateView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'registroDispositivo.html'
    form_class = RegistroDevice
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.usuario = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(RegistroDispositivo, self).form_valid(form)
```

Ten en cuenta que tienes que modificar el campo de usuario de tu modelo de Device para que incluya blank=True, null=True, o el formulario no será valido.